# Isolate SCSS files from Foundation 6 for inclusion into my web dev project

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have an existing website project (PHP, Visual Studio, jQuery) and I would like to start leveraging some of the functionality/design provided by Foundation 6.

I had previously started using Foundation 5, and simply referenced the css and js files from my project. It worked as expected and life was good.

My problem began when I wanted to override some of Foundation's CSS. I started by simply overriding the classes in my own CSS file. It worked and life was good. But I realize that's not the best way to go about it, from a maintainability standpoint. So I began diving in to SASS/SCSS. It seemed that Foundation 6 was the way to go. I installed all kinds of stuff to get it working.... node, ruby, gems, the Foundation CLI, and probably some others that elude me at the moment.

I created a new Foundation project, so that I could isolate out the necessary files and include them into my VS project -- I figured, however naively so, that I could copy over the necessary css, scss, and js files into my VS project, and then when I edited the scss file(s), I could compile them to css. (Compiling could be done any number of ways, from sass command line to VS extensions).

But the only scss files I found in the created project were

- _settings.scss
- app.scss

When I attempted to compile app.scss, I got an error: "file to import not found or unreadable: functions" and so I went looking for the missing file but cannot find it anywhere.

I looked through the bower_components folder and found a whole bunch of scss files in there, but none named *functions*.

**Is there somewhere I can easily obtain all the scss files necessary to compile my customizations to Foundation's CSS?**

Bonus question: Am I completely nuts trying to develop in this manner, instead of subscribing to the whole kit-and-kaboodle of Foundation's way of doing things from a project perspective?

Comment: What were you using to compile the SCSS?

Comment: LibSassNet via the SassyStudio extension for Visual Studio. I don't think the issue is directly related to that extension though.... If I attempted to compile outside of VS using sass command line, I think I'd get the same error since I only have the two scss files mentioned above and the _settings.scss file references the functions.scss file which I do not have a copy of.

Comment: Where did you get the `_settings.scss` file from? There is no reference to a `_functions.scss` file in the F6 settings.

Comment: From the zip file I downloaded via the "Download Basic Template" link on the Foundation 6.0 "Getting Started" page: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/starter-projects.html where it states, "Our basic project template is a lot like the Sass template from Foundation 5. The project has a flat directory structure and only compiles Sass. It's great if you want to quickly put together a simple project and only need to use Sass."

Comment: Sorry, Colin, the plot thickens.... I re-downloaded that zip file (mentioned a moment ago) and attempted to compile the app.scss file.... This time I got an error about missing "motion-ui" which I see in an @import statement on line 5 of app.scss.... but I'm not sure where to obtain that file from. Thanks for your responses thus far!

Comment: If you run `npm install` then run `bower install` it will install all the dependencies. After running those, run `gulp` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I followed your instructions (after creating a new Basic Template test project by using `foundation new`.) I still only see the two original .scss files in my scss folder. I do see `motion-ui.scss` here: `bower_components\motion-ui\motion-ui.scss` but what I'm trying to do is easily isolate all the scss files so I can integrate them into an already existing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that Foundation 6 is quite different from Foundation 5 in relation to CSS, SCSS, and the overriding of styles. In version 5, the Foundation files included a couple of basic scss files which provided the means to easily override classes.

In Foundation 6, things work MUCH differently. There are over 100 SCSS files provided, and all are necessary when tweaking the `_settings.scss` file, as they are all used in compiling the final `app.css` file.

To answer my own question, **it can't be done**, and/or, **it doesn't work that way.**

My final solution was to build a new Foundation 6 template within my existing Visual Studio project's folder structure. I then included the necessary scss files (`_settings.scss` and `app.scss`) in my project and source control.

This config allows me to edit the scss files within Visual Studio, and allow Foundation etc (using the `foundation watch` command) to compile those changes into the final css used by the rest of my project.

A bit of a hybrid approach, but ultimately effective and easy enough to maintain.

Comment: I was going to suggest you do something similar except that you install foundation-sites through bower into your existing project (as opposed to moving the existing project into a foundation template). Then you import all of the SCSS in a similar fashion to how the foundation templates work with the settings file and app.scss.